# How to mock side plugin when testing Vue component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I use Vue 2, vue-test-utils, jest

Plugin is vue-croppa for uploading pictures.

```
import Croppa from 'vue-croppa'
Vue.use(Croppa, { componentName: 'image-croppa' })
```

It's mounted to my component through v-model. Then i can call some methods on it.

**template**

```
<image-croppa v-model="myCroppa" ...>
```

**script**

```
data() {
  return {
    myCroppa: {},
  }
},
```

Also i have some method that calls vue-croppa method.

```
handlePicture(){
    const dataUri = this.myCroppa.generateDataUrl()
    this.$emit('got-image', dataUri)
  },
```

I want to test my method calls vue-croppa method.

**the question is:**

How can i mock this plugin, when initializing my component in a test? 
AND is there a need to test this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Side note: Your setup is a little confusing to me. Why is `myCroppa` declared as a data element? Isn't the vue-croppa plugin responsible for injecting `this.myCroppa`? I would imagine that having both might cause problems.

Anyway, you can pass a `mocks` option when instantiating your component in a test:

```
const mockCroppa = {
  get() => '/fake-url'
}

mount(MyComponent, {
  mocks: {
    myCroppa: mockCroppa
  }
}
```

Source: https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/#mocking-injections

To your second question, it's worth it IMO to test that an event is emitted with the correct `dataUri` when the `handlePicture` callback is triggered by a `click` event on your component, or something similar. Trigger that via `wrapper.trigger(...)` in your test and assert that `wrapper.emitted()['got-image']` is what it should be.